# Call a function from scan in Theano

Tags: theano

I need to execute a theano function a number of times via scan in order to sum-up a cost function and use it in a gradient computation.  I'm familiar with the deep-learning tutorials that do this but my data slicing and some other complications means I need to do this a little different.
Below is a much simplified version of what I'm trying to do..

```
tn = testnet()
cost = tn.single_cost( )
x = theano.shared(numpy.asarray([7.1,2.2,3.4], dtype='float32'))
index = T.lscalar('index')
test_fn = theano.function(inputs=[index], outputs=cost, 
    givens={tn.x:x[index:index+1]} )

def step(curr):
    return T.constant( test_fn( curr ) )
outs,_ = theano.scan(step, T.arange(2))

out_fn = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=outs)
print out_fn()
```

In the scan function, the call to test_fn(curr) is giving the error... 
Expected an array-like object, but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared) variable instead of a numeric array?')

Even if I pass in an array of values instead of putting the T.arrange(2) in place, I still get the same error.  Is there a reason you can't call a function from scan?

In general I'm wondering if there is a way to call a function like this with a series of indexes so that the output can feed into a T.grad() computation (not shown).

Answer (score 3):

Don't make two different `theano.functions`.

A `theano.function` takes a symbolic relationship, optimizes it, and compiles it.  What you are doing here is asking `theano.scan` (and thus `out_fn`) to consider a compiled function as a symbolic relationship.  Whether you could *technically* get that to work I'm not sure, but it goes against the idea of Theano.

Since I don't know what your cost function does here I can't give an exact example, but here's a quick example which does work and should be similar enough to what I *think* you're trying to do.

```
x = theano.shared(np.asarray([7.1,2.2,3.4], dtype = np.float32))

v = T.vector("v")
def fv(v):
    res,_ = theano.scan(lambda x: x ** 2, v)
    return T.sum(res)

def f(i):
    return fv(x[i:i+2])

outs,_ = theano.scan(
    f, 
    T.arange(2)
    )

fn = theano.function(
    [],
    outs,
    )

fn()
```

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I agree that calling a function from a function is not correct.  The challenge with the code is that following the basic design of the deep-learning tutorials, the first layer of the net has a symbolic variable defined as it's input and the output is propagated up to higher layers until a final cost is computed from the top layer.  The tutorials uses code something like...

```
class layer1(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.x = T.matrix()
      self.output = activation(T.dot(self.x,self.W) + self.b)
```

For me the tensor variable (layer1.self.x) needs to change every time scan takes a step to have a new slice of data. The "givens" statement in a function does that, but since calling a compiled theano function from inside a "scan" doesn't work there are two other solutions I was able to find...

1 - Rework the network so that its cost function is based on a series of function calls instead of a propagated variable.  This is technically simple but requires a bit of re-coding to get things organized properly in a multi-layer network.

2 - Use theano.clone inside of scan.  That code looks something like...

```
def step(curr):
    y_in = y[curr]
    replaces = {tn.layer1.x : x[curr:curr+1]}
    fn = theano.clone(tn.cost(y_in), replace=replaces)
    return fn
outs,_ = theano.scan(step, sequences=[T.arange(batch_start,batch_end)])
```

Both methods return the same results and appear execute at the same speed.

Comment: @bivuac0 -- I came to the same issue you did, apparently the same way, which is trying to modify the deeplearning examples.  I suspect we're trying to do similar things.  In my case, I'd like to use the RBM and SdA examples to train networks based on a large dataset, which is sparse o CPU, that I copy to the GPU in sets, dense.  I'd really appreciate if you could elaborate on what you learned solving this problem, and how different approaches panned-out.

Comment: Bob: The answer directly above is me documenting what I learned when I looked into the issue.  The two solutions posted are what I came up with.  I'd be happy to try to help with your specific issue but I'd need to know a little more detail.  You can ask me a question directly from my profile here but there's also a very active "Theano-users" group on Google-groups where you could get your question answered too.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up posting to the list this afternoon. The scan/clone strategy broke down as soon as I tried to figure out a way to deal with updates.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

The standard way is `OpFromGraph` (as of 0.8.2)

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.scalar('x')
y = T.scalar('y')
z = x+y
# unlike theano.function, must use list for outputs
op_add = th.OpFromGraph([x,y], [z])

def my_add(x_, y_):
    return op_add(x_, y_)[0]

x_list = T.vector('x_li')
x_sum = th.scan(op_add, sequences=[x_list], outputs_info=[T.constant(0.)])
fn_sum = th.function([x_list], x_sum)
fn([1., 2., 3., 4.]) # 10.
```

#### What it does?

`OpFromGraph` compiles a function defined from a graph, then pack it into a new Op. Just like defining functions in imperative programming languages.

#### Pros/Cons

- [+] It can be handy in tricky models.
- [+] It saves compilation time. You can compile a commonly used part of a big model into `OpFromGraph`, then directly use it in a bigger model. The final graph will have less nodes than direct implementation.
- [-] It cause worse runtime performance. Calling a function has overhead, also the compiler is unable to do a global optimization due to its compiled nature.
- [-] It's premature and still under development. The documentation for it is incomplete. Currently does not support `updates` and `givens` as in `theano.function`.

#### Notes

In most cases, you should be defining python functions/classes to build model. Only use `OpFromGraph` if no workaround is possible or you want to save compilation time.